# Using spread operator from es6 in react-redux app with stage-2 loader

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am using ES6 spread operator in my react-redux app like this way

```
var defaultState = {val:1, items:[]};
export default function(state=defaultState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_BOOK':
    state.val = 0;
    return {
      ...state,
      items:action.payload.data.result
    };
```

The problem is each time I get fresh data from `action.payload.data.result` assigned to items. I want to have concatenated data from previous state. Can someone help.

Comment: ````return { ...state, items: [ ...state.items, ...action.payload.data.result ] }```` should work.

Comment: ES6 has no spread syntax for objects!

Comment: `{ ...state, items: state.items.concat(action.payload.data.result)`

Comment: It seems that he is using the plugin "transform-object-rest-spread" or something like that.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
return {
  ...state,
  items: [
    ...state.items,
    ...aciton.payload.data.result
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so what you really need to do here, is concat the existing items *and* those returned from your payload.

Assuming this is the case, then you need to create a new array from the old items array and new. [You also want to avoid mutating the existing state.](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html)

Return a completely new state from your reducer. Do this by cloning the existing state and adding your new items array:

```
case 'ADD_BOOK':
    var newState = Object.assign({}, state, {val:0}); // clones the existing state and adds our new val
    newState.items = newState.Items.concat(action.payload.data.result);
    return newState;
```

There are cleaner ways to do this with the spread syntax or libraries such as immutable but this example will explicitly achieve what we need to do.